# Search strings in dataframe for specific pattern and update with another column

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have the following toy dataframe:

```
ID <- c(15, 25, 90, 1, 23, 543)

HTML <- c("[demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]", "<text-ali>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]", "[social_isolation][1]<div></table<div><text-align>[social_isolation_date][1]", "<text-align>[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]", "<div>[demography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[demography_form_date][1]", "[geography_form][1]<div></table<text-align>[geography_form_date][1]</table")

df <- data.frame(ID, HTML)
```

[image]

How can I search each string in the `HTML` column for occrrances of the integer surrounded by square brackets, replacing that value with the integer in the adjacent `ID` column? If there is no square brackets with an integer in the row I would like no operation to occur. Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple occurrences in each string. Do you care about which one to use?

Comment: @r2evans, I would like to update all occurrences in each string. Thank you

Comment: Sorry ... I had it reversed ... I was thinking of replacing `ID` with the number in the brackets, my bad :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_replace` to replace only the first occurrence.

```
library(stringr)

df$HTML <- str_replace_all(df$HTML, "\\[\\d\\]", str_c("[", df$ID, "]"))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(HTML = str_replace_all(HTML, "\\[\\d\\]", str_c("[", ID, "]")))
```